# How to format Excel Date into PHP?

Tags: php, excel, date

In my excel, i have this date of the format `d-M-y`. My problem is upon import, the date becomes `b115-Oct-04` instead of `15-Oct-04`.

If i use:

```php
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-M-y', $sheetData[$i][3]);
```

I receive this error:

> Unexpected data found. The separation symbol could not be found. Trailing data

And if I use this:

```php
$date = date_format(date_create($sheetData[$i][3]), "F d, Y");
```

I am receiving this error:

> date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given

Comment: Seem like the `b1` in the string is the column or row number in the excel. You need to strip it off before passing to the function else will cause the error.

Comment: The second method fails because `date_create()` returns false then it fails to create new `DateTime` instance. And `date_format()` is expecting a `DateTime` object.